# Ignore if Array in Range Not Exist Excel Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Supposed I have data like this:

```
Range:
  |  A  |  B  |    C   | D |
1 | 50  | 100 | Range1 |   |
2 | 150 | 200 | Range2 |   |
3 | 250 | 300 | Range3 |   |
4 | 350 | 400 | Range4 |   |
Input:
5 |  36 | 324 |  271   |   |
```

By using the following formula will give right result: **Range3** (which is that I want), because the range already there.

```
=INDEX(C1:C4;SUMPRODUCT(--(C5<=B1:B4);--(C5>=A1:A4);ROW(D1:D4)))
```

But by using same formula with different Input it will give error's result: #VALUE! because the range is not exist.

```
=INDEX(C1:C4;SUMPRODUCT(--(A5<=B1:B4);--(A5>=A1:A4);ROW(D1:D4)))
```

or

```
=INDEX(C1:C4;SUMPRODUCT(--(B5<=B1:B4);--(B5>=A1:A4);ROW(D1:D4)))
```

So how to handle the error if the range not exist by using formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `IFERROR` function like this to handle errors -

`=IFERROR(INDEX(C1:C4;SUMPRODUCT(--(C5<=B1:B4);--(C5>=A1:A4);ROW(D1:D4))); "Range doesn't exist")`